# Create a complex query from two tables with a hierarchical structure in SQL Alchemy

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I have two tables in database in Flask. They have this structure:

```
class Tasks(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'tasks'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    task = db.Column(db.Text)

    topics = db.relationship('Topics')
    topics_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('topics.id'))

class Topics(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'topics'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(140))
    parent = db.Column(db.Integer, default=0)
    task = db.relationship("Tasks", back_populates='topics')
```

The Topic table is:

| id | name | parent |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Mathematics | 0 |
| 2 | Algebra | 1 |
| 3 | Progression | 2 |
| 4 | Number sequences | 3 |

The task table is

| id | task | topics_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1+2+3+4 | 4 |
| 2 | 6+7+8+9 | 4 |
| 3 | 6+7+8+9 +10 | 4 |
| 4 | 6+7+8+9 +10+11 | 4 |

I need to get this output from running a query:

| task | subject | category | topic | subtopic |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1+2+3+4 | Mathematics | Algebra | Progression | Number sequences |
| 6+7+8+9 | Mathematics | Algebra | Progression | Number sequences |
| 6+7+8+9 +10 | Mathematics | Algebra | Progression | Number sequences |
| 6+7+8+9 +10+11 | Mathematics | Algebra | Progression | Number sequences |

How should I solve this problem?

Comment: SQL or SQLAlchemy answer expected? What have you tried, show us your attempt.

Comment: the best option is SQLAlchemy.

Comment: @ВладимирКузовкин why?

Comment: Sorry,best is both sql and sqlalchemy.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `recursive cte` :

```
; with recursive cte as (
select id , name , parentid, 1 lvl from topics
union all 
select t.id, cte.name ,t.parentid, lvl+1 as lvl  from topics t
join cte on t.parentid = cte.id
) 
select  t.id, t.task 
      , max(cte.name) filter (where lvl =4) subject
      , max(cte.name) filter (where lvl =3) category
      , max(cte.name) filter (where lvl =2) topic
      , max(cte.name) filter (where lvl =1) subtopic
from tasks t
left join cte 
   on t.topics_id = cte.id
group by t.id, t.task
```

or if you might have not all information filled , you can use this :

```
; with recursive cte as (
select id , name , parentid, 1 lvl from topics
union all 
select t.id, cte.name ,t.parentid, lvl+1 as lvl  from topics t
join cte on t.parentid = cte.id
)
, cte2 as (
select t.id , cte.name, t.task , lvl,max(lvl) over ( partition by t.id) mlvl
from tasks t
left join cte 
 on t.topics_id = cte.id
)
select  t.id, t.task 
      , max(t.name) filter (where mlvl = lvl ) subject
      , max(t.name) filter (where mlvl = lvl + 1) category
      , max(t.name) filter (where mlvl = lvl + 2) topic
      , max(t.name) filter (where mlvl = lvl + 3) subtopic
from cte2 t
group by t.id, t.task
order by t.id
```